How to create a PC version of a PCB project made for RP4
I want to create a PC version of a PCB project I made for Raspberry Pi 4.
It is a simple PCB of a 5-button micropad that connects to 5 GPIO Pins (+1 3.3V GPIO for Pull UP) on the RP and using the python RPi.GPIO library I wrote a script that listens for click events for each button to send a different udp command when clicked.
So I want to create a PCB version that works on windows, I'd like to add as little as possible to the PCB.
I imagine that to connect it to the PC I will have to replace the pin header with a microUSB or type-C connector?
Will I have to add a microcontroller chip for Windows to recognize the PCB?
Will I have to use another language for the script that listens to button click events and sends the commands?
Since I don't need ascii keyboard functions, I won't need a keyboard library?
I've never done anything for Windows so I'm stuck, any documentation and guidance is appreciated.

The PC doesn't have GPIO (general purpose input/output) pins. One of the reasons for the success of the RPi was that it does and interfacing is simple. The best solution depends on your application. Can you [edit] your question to explain what the buttons are going to do on the Windows computer? You might find that an Arduino Nano or similar may make a much simpler interface between the PC and the outside world.

What do you mean by "a PCB version that works on windows"? Are you saying you want to create a PCB with a 5-button micropad on it, that you can connect to a PC running Windows, such that when you press the buttons, it will send a signal that a Windows program can detect?

hack a gamepad ... write code in Processing

use a gamepad with FreePIE and write Python script to output UDP messages

The USB Human Interface Devices (HID) class allows a USB device to send simulated keyboard (or mouse) events to a connected host computer. The USB HID class shouldn't require a specific driver on the host PC.
usb_keyboard_device is an example for a TI Cortex-M4 microcontroller with a USB device port which allows the microcontroller software to send a string to the host PC as it had been entered on a keyboard, when the microcontroller software detects a button press on a GPIO input pin.
While the referenced example isn't for a Raspberry Pi 4, it should serve as a starting point on what to look for how get Raspberry Pi 4 to emulate a USB keyboard and send simulated key-presses to a Windows host PC.

Chester, as you've answered this question, and as it is a reasonable one, even though the OP does not understand the subject well, I suggest it's worth an upvote. Others will benefit from this Q&A in future.
